Выбор сервера для мобильного приложения
Изучаю мобильную разработку, а именно создаю приложение для Android на Kotlin.
Приложение простое, в основном это работа в БД, есть регистрация и авторизация.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что выбрать для серверной части?
Имеется опыт в создании сервера на Python для телеграм-ботов. Создавал веб-сервера для сайтов на Apache и Nginx.
Но как-то все это не очень подходит, по моему мнению, для мобильного приложения.
Подумывал над Ktor, но инфы в инете по нему очень мало, да и кажется мне громоздким.
Просто хочу сделать сервер, который будет работать с регистрацией, авторизацией и общаться с БД (Postgres), к чему присмотреться?

К чему угодно, да какая разница вообще

REST, JSON, возможно GraphQL -- вот основные базворды для сервера мобильного приложения. Т.е. дизайн API имеет большее значение чем фреймворк или тип сервера.

Можно да, на чём угодно делать. API, да, во многом важнее. Если хотите на том же языке писать то да - берите относительно новый Ktor или Spring. По Spring сеть полна инфы, но это он громоздкий шо ппц. Ktor, по идее, будет проще для понимания. Но инфы по нему да, меньше. Лично я на Spring серверные части делаю. Вполне норм, но по началу - сложно.

Я бы остановился на Spring Boot, Ktor считаю сыроват еще
